# How to install clangd (not clang) on mac os

Tags: macos, clang

I installed `xcode, llvm, brew`, and I have `clang` on my system but not `clangd` ..., I googled around and only find how install `clang` not `clangd`.
I tried `brew install clangd` but not found clangd. I even tried to go through the docs of llvm and still could not find the answer...

Comment: [clangd](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clangd/) is a language server that implements the Language Server Protocol; it can work with many editors through a [plugin](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clangd/Installation.html#id3). [Installing clangd](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clangd/Installation.html#installing-clangd).

Comment: understood, and that is what i did `brew install llvm` but after that i still dont have `clangd`... i only have `clang` and `clang++`

Comment: `clangd is present in the MacOS binary llvm 8.0.0 release on the LLVM Download Page mentioned on the web page in the installing clangd  link.  It's also present in the previous prebuilt MacOS binary llvm 7.0.0.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a pretty useful answer and pretty useful question...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After `brew install llvm`, my Mac provides

```
$ find  /usr/local/ -name 'clangd'
/usr/local//Cellar/llvm/8.0.0_1/bin/clangd
/usr/local//Cellar/llvm/8.0.0_1/Toolchains/LLVM8.0.0.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clangd
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a pretty useful answer and pretty useful question...

Answer (score 1):

Here is another related question you should see to set that up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185976/how-to-install-clangd-on-mac

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174).